# HTML5 Media Capture crashes on Android when uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, android, html, crash, html5-canvas

I face problems with my HTML5 App for decoding barcodes with JavaScript. For testing reasons I run the implemented algorithms against a database with 1055 pictures (Muenster BarcodeDB with a resolution of 600x800px). It works fine in Chrome on Windows and Safari on iPad 2. But Chrome on my Moto G (Android) crashes after 20-30 pictures without any message. When I use HTML5 Media Capture with camera photos it also crashes after taking several pictures and Chrome reports, that there isn't enough memory for the previous operation. It crashes directly, when the picture was taken and the camera app is closed. Then the browser is shown again with a reaload of the page.

Did anyone face the same problems? Below is some code on how to use the pictures.

HTML Media Capture Input:

```
<input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" capture style="display:none;">
```

JavaScript Handler (exif.js, megapixImg.js for rotating/scaling image):

```
fileInput.onchange = function () {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    imgOrientation = null;

    // get orientation of image from exif data
    EXIF.getData(file, function () {
        imgOrientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");
    });

    // MegaPixImage constructor accepts File/Blob object.
    megapixImg = new MegaPixImage(file);

    // Render resized image into image element using quality option.
    // Quality option is valid when rendering into image element.
    megapixImg.render(tempImg, { maxWidth: maxDimension, maxHeight: maxDimension, quality: 1.0 });
};

tempImg.onload = function () {
    // Render resized image into canvas element.
    megapixImg.render(tempCanvas, { maxWidth: maxDimension, maxHeight: maxDimension, orientation: imgOrientation });

    // TRIGGER ALGORITHM
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For your HTML5 media capture problem, you are likely running into the following bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53088

Unfortunately, the android developers have marked the issue as obsolete, which it is not.  A few potential workarounds are discussed in the aforementioned thread, but none of them really suit my needs.  Maybe you will have better luck.  :)

Comment: Thanks for this link, too bad it's marked as "obsolete". Last week, I tried two things. Scale down resolution for the camera (doesn't work mit Moto G standard camera, but on Samsung Galaxy S5 it has the option), so the memory usage is lowered. Also, I used this [Chrome setting](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/21r0a6/how_i_sped_up_chrome_on_my_device) to allow more memory usage on my Moto G (from 128MB to 512 MB). Haven't done real tests on how much this actually helps. But my first impression was, that it works a lot better!